# Numbers to rounded off text

Tags: c#

I am using the following function to convert numbers to text:

```
public static string NumberToText(long number)
{
   StringBuilder wordNumber = new StringBuilder();

   string[] powers = new string[] { "Thousand ", "Million ", "Billion " };
   string[] tens = new string[] { "Twenty", "Thirty", "Forty", "Fifty", "Sixty", "Seventy", "Eighty", "Ninety" };
   string[] ones = new string[] { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", 
                               "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen", "Fourteen", "Fifteen", "Sixteen", "Seventeen", "Eighteen", "Nineteen" };

   if (number == 0) { return "Zero"; }
   if (number < 0)
   {
       wordNumber.Append("Negative ");
       number = -number;
   }

   long[] groupedNumber = new long[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
   int groupIndex = 0;

   while (number > 0)
   {
       groupedNumber[groupIndex++] = number % 1000;
       number /= 1000;
   }

   for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--)
   {
       long group = groupedNumber[i];

       if (group >= 100)
       {
           wordNumber.Append(ones[group / 100 - 1] + " Hundred ");
           group %= 100;

           if (group == 0 && i > 0)
               wordNumber.Append(powers[i - 1]);
       }

       if (group >= 20)
       {
           if ((group % 10) != 0)
               wordNumber.Append(tens[group / 10 - 2] + " " + ones[group % 10 - 1] + " ");
           else
               wordNumber.Append(tens[group / 10 - 2] + " ");
       }
       else if (group > 0)
           wordNumber.Append(ones[group - 1] + " ");

       if (group != 0 && i > 0)
           wordNumber.Append(powers[i - 1]);
   }

   return wordNumber.ToString().Trim();
}
```

This works fine.

The issue is that the returned text is too long to read. I want to convert it to something shorter.

For eg: **345435234** is returned as three hundred and forty-five million, four hundred and thirty-five thousand, two hundred and thirty-four.

I instead would like 345.4 Mil.

Here are some more examples:

```
3454 should be 3.4K  
34543 should be 34.5K  
345433 should be 345.4K  
... and so on.
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Through programming? Give it a try. If you wrote the above, this should not be too hard. If you get stuck, ask a *specific* question here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

Though if you have "*printable character OCD*" you could probably get it smaller

```
private static string[] suffixes = new[] { "", "K", "Mill", "Bill", "Trill", "Zill" };

public static string ToStuff(double number, int precision = 2)
{
    const double unit = 1000;
    var  i = 0;
    while (number > unit)
    {
        number /= unit;
        i++;
    }
    if(i >= 5) throw new Exception("No one can count this high");
    return Math.Round(number, precision, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) + suffixes[i];
}
```

***Disclaimer*** : Totally untested

**Update**

Due to popular demand, i tested it with a test case of 1 E.g `2500000, 0` and it output `2Mill`. I think i might have a career in this counting game

**Update 2**

Due to more popular demand, the consensus is that we shouldn't use .Net default rounding `ToEven` (bankers rounding) , and should use `AwayFromZero`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
if (number>1000000)
   string = floor(number/1000000).ToString() + "m";
else if (number > 1000)
   string = floor(number/1000).ToString() + "k";
else
   string = number.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution works. Michael's answer was much cleaner and taught me a few new things.